# PHP if() not working right

Tags: php, html

I am using the cbpFixedScrollLayout to create a long scrolling website, and one of the sections has a restaurant menu in it.
The navigation for the menu is:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="?m=Rest#fbsection3">Rest</a></li>
  <li><a href="?m=TA#fbsection3">TA</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the php is

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET)) $menu = "Rest";
else $menu = $_GET["m"];

if ($menu="Rest"){echo"REST";}elseif($menu="TA"){echo"TAKEAWAY";}

?>
```

But for some reason this is not working. I can't figure it out. Help?!

Comment: Ofc its the if. lol. Learn what operators do ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tests in `if` statement has to have `==`, not `=`, so:

```
if ($menu == "Rest"){
    echo "REST";
} elseif ($menu == "TA"){
    echo "TAKEAWAY";
}
```

Single `=` assigns value to the variable, so it always returns true.

Comment: Brilliant! Knew i'd missed something.

Comment: @user3364292 You're welcome. If you find my answer helpful, remember to accept it with the thick on the left.

Comment: Will do when I can - you can see where my problem was on this website:

http://toladverts.co.uk/cafe%20bangla

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
if ($menu="Rest"){echo"REST";}elseif($menu="TA"){echo"TAKEAWAY";}
```

should be

```
if ($menu=="Rest"){echo"REST";}elseif($menu=="TA"){echo"TAKEAWAY";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, Be careful when using the empty() function with $_GET Array. The array might not always be empty even if there are no Get variables defined. Same goes for other global variables.

Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

Check with isset if you send data, and on if condition use "==" or "===", here an example:

```
if (isset($_GET["m"])) {
    if ($_GET["m"] == "Rest") {
        # code... "m = Rest"
    } elseif ($_GET["m"] == "TA") {
        # code... "m = TA"
    }

} else {
    # code... "m is empty"
}
```